# How to test mptt model?

Tags: python, django

There is my first steps in django testing.

What I testing in current case:

I use MPTT in my project and when new instance created - it's parent instance obtaining new value of date field.

What is a problem:

after creating instances in setUp method in TestCase, TreeNode.objects.get() can't find a created instance or django don't see three or I don't know what happens, but creating new child described in TreeNode.save() in bottom not works.

For exapmple after

```
TreeNode.objects.create(id=4, parent_id=1)
```

TreeNode.objects.get(id=4).level (autofield in mptt) equals None but must be 0 if instance have no parent or parent.level+1 if parent exists. Sometimes TreeNode.objects.get(id=4) simply can't find the object that has been created by TreeNode.objects.create(id=4).

goal: define OK method for creating a child Node that takes contract_date, id and parent as attributes and after TreeNode.objects.create running save() as is.

There are a lot of questions and I would like to get answers for part of them. Main questions are:

How to create TreeNode object in test (or in model, if I do anything wrong)?
How to correctly define object as a child element of another TreeNode?

My code:

Tests:

```
# method for creating a newbie. 
def instantiate_treenode(uid, contract_date, parent_id=None):
TreeNode.objects.create(id=uid,
                                 contract_date=contract_date,
                                 date_of_birth=date.today(),
                                 account_id=uid,
                                 identity_expire_date=date.today(),
                                 parent=TreeNode.objects.get(id=parent_id) if parent_id else None,)


class BigTestTree(TestCase):
#
#
#
#       #
#####   #
def setUp(self):
    instantiate_treenode(uid=1, contract_date=date(2014, 1, 1))

    instantiate_treenode(uid=2, contract_date=date(2014, 1, 2), parent_id=1)

    instantiate_treenode(uid=3, contract_date=date(2014, 1, 3), parent_id=2)

    instantiate_treenode(uid=4, contract_date=date(2014, 1, 4), parent_id=3)
    instantiate_treenode(uid=5, contract_date=date(2014, 1, 5), parent_id=3)

    instantiate_treenode(uid=6, contract_date=date(2014, 1, 6), parent_id=4)
    instantiate_treenode(uid=7, contract_date=date(2014, 1, 7), parent_id=4)
    instantiate_treenode(uid=8, contract_date=date(2014, 1, 8), parent_id=4)
    instantiate_treenode(uid=9, contract_date=date(2014, 1, 9), parent_id=4)

    for i in range(1, 10):
        self.assertEqual(TreeNode.objects.get(id=i).paid_income, 0)

def test_add_newbies_to_fourth_line(self):

    instantiate_treenode(uid=11, contract_date=date(2014, 1, 10), parent_id=5)

    self.assertEqual(TreeNode.objects.get(id=1).expected_income, 5 * 550)
    self.assertEqual(TreeNode.objects.get(id=2).paid_income, 5 * 1000)

    for i in range(3, 10):
        self.assertEqual(TreeNode.objects.get(id=i).paid_income, 0)

    self.assertEqual(TreeNode.objects.get(id=7).is_parent_rewarded(3), True)
    self.assertEqual(TreeNode.objects.get(id=7).is_parent_rewarded(1), False)

    instantiate_treenode(uid=10, contract_date=date(2014, 1, 10), left=13, right=14, lvl=4,
                         parent_id=4)

    self.assertEqual(TreeNode.objects.get(id=1).paid_income, 5 * 550)
    self.assertEqual(TreeNode.objects.get(id=2).paid_income, 5 * 1000)
    self.assertEqual(TreeNode.objects.get(id=3).paid_income, 5 * 3500)
    self.assertEqual(TreeNode.objects.get(id=4).paid_income, 5 * 5400)

    for i in range(5, 10):
        self.assertEqual(TreeNode.objects.get(id=i).paid_income, 0)
```

MPTT Model

```
class TreeNode(MPTTModel):

    account = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, verbose_name='Аккаунт')

    # contract
    id = models.CharField(verbose_name='ID', max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', verbose_name='ID пригласившего', null=True, blank=True, related_name='child')
    contract_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)  

    invite_period_expire_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def is_parent_rewarded(self, line):
        return getattr(self, self.rewarded_parents_fields[line - 1]) if line else self

    def get_parent_of_level(self, level):
        if self.get_level() - level >= 0:
            return self.get_ancestors().get(level=self.get_level() - level)
        return None

    def get_relative_level(self, level, newbies_only):
        result = self.get_descendants().filter(level=self.get_level() + level)
        if newbies_only:
            result = filter(lambda x: not x.is_parent_rewarded(level), result)
        return result

    def pay_to_parent(self, line, five_per_period):
        parent = self.get_parent_of_level(line)
        if parent:
            from payments.models import CompanyToClientPayment

            if line == 1:
                payment = CompanyToClientPayment.objects.create(client=parent, use_date=self.contract_date,
                                                                total=prices[0][1]
                                                                if five_per_period
                                                                else prices[0][0])
            elif line == 2:
                payment = CompanyToClientPayment.objects.create(client=parent, use_date=self.contract_date,
                                                                total=prices[1][1]
                                                                if five_per_period
                                                                else prices[1][0])
            elif line == 3:
                payment = CompanyToClientPayment.objects.create(client=parent,
                                                                use_date=self.contract_date
                                                                if self.contract_date.day <= 5
                                                                else next_fifth_day_of_month(self.contract_date),
                                                                total=prices[2])
            elif line == 4:
                payment = CompanyToClientPayment.objects.create(client=parent,
                                                                use_date=self.contract_date
                                                                if self.contract_date.day <= 5
                                                                else next_fifth_day_of_month(self.contract_date),
                                                                total=prices[3])
            else:

                raise ValueError('Invalid line to pay for invite')

            #print('paymentID' + str(payment.id))
        setattr(self, self.rewarded_parents_fields[line - 1], True)
        self.save()
        parent.save()
        # print getattr(self, self.rewarded_parents_fields[line-1])

    def close_invite_period(self, expired):
        for child in filter(lambda x: x.contract_date <= self.invite_period_expire_date,
                            self.get_relative_level(level=1, newbies_only=True)):
            child.pay_to_parent(1, five_per_period=not expired)

            if child.get_parent_of_level(2):
                child.pay_to_parent(2, five_per_period=not expired)

        self.invite_period_expire_date = None
        self.save()

    def start_invite_period(self, start_date):
        if self.invite_period_expire_date:
            raise ReopeningInvitePeriodException
        self.invite_period_expire_date = start_date + invite_period
        self.save()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if self.get_parent_of_level(1) and TreeNode.objects.filter(id=self.id).exists():
            if not self.get_parent_of_level(1).invite_period_expire_date:
                self.get_parent_of_level(1).start_invite_period(self.contract_date)
            elif self.get_parent_of_level(1).invite_period_expire_date <= self.contract_date:
                self.get_parent_of_level(1).close_invite_period(expired=True)
                self.get_parent_of_level(1).start_invite_period(self.contract_date)

            newbie_brothers = self.get_parent_of_level(1).get_relative_level(level=1, newbies_only=True)

            if len(newbie_brothers) == 5:
                self.get_parent_of_level(1).close_invite_period(expired=False)

            if self.get_parent_of_level(3):
                newbie_brothers = self.get_parent_of_level(3).get_relative_level(level=3, newbies_only=True)
                if len(newbie_brothers) == 5:
                    for newbie in newbie_brothers:
                        newbie.pay_to_parent(3, five_per_period=False)

                if self.get_parent_of_level(4):
                    newbie_brothers = self.get_parent_of_level(4).get_relative_level(level=4, newbies_only=True)
                    if len(newbie_brothers) == 5:
                        for newbie in newbie_brothers:
                            newbie.pay_to_parent(4, five_per_period=False)
        super(TreeNode, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Why are you defining id as a CharField rather than using the default autoincremented int?

Comment: Every client have an ID generated by company. It includes country code. Because of it I use custom id field instead of autoincrement id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my problem was that I thought that `instance.save()` makes 'update' query if object already exists. I was wrong. For calling 'update' query `instance.update(*kwargs)` method should be called. I'm sorry. I'm a teapot.